Unittest can't find imported module in imported module
Unittest modules import issue
My project folder structure goes like this:
project/
  __init__.py (empty)
  tests/
    __init__.py (empty)
    tests.py
  src/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
    c.py      

tests/tests.py
import unittest
from a import A

my_a = A()
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    # Some tests
    pass

src/init.py
__all__ = ["a", "b", "c"]

src/a.py
from b import B

src/b.py
from c import C

src/c.py
pass

Everything works fine when I run the code from the command line but testing it throws this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
I did lots of research that I could condensed to these links:

Python unittest failing to resolve import statements
Running unittest with typical test directory structure
How do I write good/correct package __init__.py files
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Right now I'm really confused about how __init__.py would work in this case and why my test can't find imported modules path. Can anyone lend me a hand with this please?

is your project installed?

Take a look at the two common layout of Python Projects. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/ At the moment you have a package called src (which I suspect isn't what you wanted). However, from src.a import A etc should work.

Thanks for the comment. I've found a similar solution Ahmad's answer.

from .b import B
from .c import C

Sorry, I get ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package when I run python a.py

It actually helped. I've got to use python -m a.a to run the module
